# Outlook attachments send then move

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

how do I move the files once its been send out successfully to **`c:\complete`**

Can I limit the attachments to 10 attachments per email. 
each file size is like 300kb

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendMessage(Optional AttachmentPath)
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim objOutlookFile As String


    '// Attachment Path
    AttachmentPath = "C:\Reports\"

    '// Create the Outlook session.
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    '// Create the message.
    Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objOutlookMsg
        '// Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
        Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("omar")
        Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("omar")
            objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

        '// Add the CC recipient(s) to the message.
        Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("omar")
            objOutlookRecip.Type = olCC

        '// Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
        .Subject = "Reports"
        .Body = "the Attached reports are complete !" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh  '//High importance

        '// Add attachments to the message.
        objOutlookFile = Dir(AttachmentPath & "*.*")

        Do While Len(objOutlookFile) > 0
            .Attachments.Add AttachmentPath & objOutlookFile
            objOutlookFile = Dir
        Loop

        '// Resolve each Recipient's name.
        For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients
            objOutlookRecip.Resolve
            If Not objOutlookRecip.Resolve Then
            objOutlookMsg.Display
        End If
        Next
        '//.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
        '//.Send
        .Display

    End With
    Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear where you run the VBA macro code (Outlook, Word, Excel and etc.).

Anyway, there is no need to create a new Outlook Application instance in the Outlook VBA macro:

```
'// Create the Outlook session.
 Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Instead, you can use the Application property, for example:

```
'// Create the message.
Set objOutlookMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

You can use the [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278516.aspx) for managing files on the disk. See [Accessing Files with FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711216(v=vs.71).aspx) for more information.

Also the Outlook object model provides the [BeforeAttachmentAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869511(v=office.15).aspx) event for Outlook items which is fired before an attachment is added to an instance of the parent object. It provides an instance of the Attachment class to be added and the Cancel parameter which can be used to cancel the action. Just set to true to cancel the operation; otherwise, set to false to allow the Attachment to be added.

> sorry one more question, can I stop outgoing email if there is no files in c:\reports\

The best way is to check the folder before runnig the VBA macro. You can use the FileSystemObject to get the job done.

The Application class from the Outlook object model provides the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program. It provides the item reference being sent and the Cancel parameter. If the event procedure sets the Cancel argument to true, the send action is not completed and the inspector is left open.

You can use both these events to check out whatever you need.

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article in MSDN helpful.